# What is the best practice of handling Alamofire response If I only need one string from Json

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a question about handling response of Alamofire json, I need some advice. I use SwiftyJSON to parse json.  Returned json is like that;

```
        ResultCode = "122";
    ResultText = "The content of this sample could not be recognized.";
    TransactionDetails =         {
        IsComplete = 0;
        TransactionId = 9398;
        Transactionstate = OnGoing;
        Transactiontype = Authentication;
    };
    VoiceDetails =         {
        DiscardedSpeech = 1;
        ProcessResult = None;
        SpeechResult = BadContentSpeech;
        TotalSpeech = 1;
    };
};
```

}

If I only need `TransactionState` from json. Is it an acceptable way to use closure and pass this value like that?

```
if let strState : String = swiftyJsonVar["AuthVoicePrintData"]["TransactionDetails"]["TransactionState"].string
      {
          completionHandler(strState)
          return
      }
      completionHandler("Something went wrong")
```

Or even If i need only `TransactionState` , still I should use something like  ObjectMapper` and map all these values in a model class to use where I need? Thank you.

Comment: Have you researched the use of `.isEmpty` to check if a value exists for the string?

Comment: Yes i am aware of isEmpty,  do you suggest this instead of using if let condition? thanks

Comment: Are you checking if the value exists or how to pass the value on? Question seems vague reading it again.

Comment: Sorry about my English. Actually looking for the right way to pass the value.  "if let" condition checking the value if exist or not,  if exist, it pass the value using the closure, if not exist passing the string "Something went wrong". I was asking if it is acceptable way to pass value, or it is better to create model data and map it using something like objectmapper.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it an acceptable way to use closure and pass this value like that?

Yes , it's the only right way to handle asynchronous calls

> Even If i need only TransactionState , still I should use something like ObjectMapper` and map all these values in a model class

No you don't need them nor Codable , using swifty json here is the shortest path also jsonSerialization can do the job